# PHP Session with JavaScript and AJAX Unexpected Output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's my problem. When I clicked login then submit with correct username and password it should go directly to the other page. But what happened is that it stocks on the landing page and if i refresh the page its already in the second page.

Here is the image.
[image]

Here is the code

checklogin.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once 'config.php';

try{

    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database_name . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password);

}catch(Exception $e){

    die('error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//define username and password

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE account ='$username' AND password='$password'");


$count = $stmt->rowCount();


if($count == 1){

    $_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = 'password';

}
else{
     echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Invalid username/password</div>";
}

ob_end_flush();?>
```

btn-login.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn-submit").click(function(){

  var username = $("#usr").val();
  var password = $("#pwd").val();

  if((username == "") || (password == "")) {
    $("#message").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\">Enter a username and a password");
    $('#calling-modal').modal('hide');
  }
  else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "checklogin.php",
      data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
      success: function(html){    
        if(html=='true') {
          $('#calling-modal').modal('hide');
            window.location="main.php";
        }
        else {
          $("#message").html(html);
          $('#calling-modal').modal('hide');
        }
      },
      beforeSend:function()
      {
          $("#message").html("<p class='text-center'><img src='includes/img/loader.gif'></p>")

      }
    });
  }
  return false;
}); });
```

main.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location: index.php');
}?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Got2Go Main Page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/custom-style.css">
        <script src="includes/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/js/bs-login.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container-navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">GOT2GO AIRLINES</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">        
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Booking Reservation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                     <li class="dropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <?php echo " " . $_SESSION['username']; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Logout </a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>  
</body>
```

index.php

```
<?php

  session_start();


  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      header("location: main.php"); 
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Got2Go</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/custom-style.css">
      <script src="includes/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="includes/js/bs-login.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container-fluid" id="container-navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GOT2GO AIRLINES</a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">      
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Book a flight</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li id = "right-nav" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#calling-register"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Create Account </a></li>
                  <li id = "right-nav" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#calling-modal"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!--carousel starts-->
      <section class="block">
       <div id="bluescript-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#bluescript-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#bluescript-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active" id="myslide01">
                     <img src="includes/img/large-plane03.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="item" id ="myslide01">
                    <img src="includes/img/large-plane01.jpg">
                </div>

           </div>

        </div>
      <!--carousel-->
    </section>

    <div class="container-fluid features-container" >
          <div class="container" id="inner-features">
            <div class="row" id="row-features">

              <div class="col-md-3" id="col-features">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex.
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3" id="col-features">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex.
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3" id="col-features">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex.
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3" id="col-features">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal LOGIN -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="calling-modal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="lheader-text">Login your account</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div id="message"></div>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="usr" placeholder="Enter username" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Password" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="isLoggedIn" id="btn-submit">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Modal -->
    </div>

    <footer class="container-fluid" id="footer-outer">
        <div class="container" id="footer-inner">
            <div class="row" id="footer-contents">

                <div class="col-sm-2 visible-md-lg" id="col-features">
                    <h6>Copyright &copy; 2015 </h6>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <h6>About us</h6>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class= "col-sm-2">
                    <h6>Like our page</h6>
                    <p>
                       <a href="http://www.facebok.com">Facebook</a>
                       <br>
                       <a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
                       <br>
                       <a href="http://www.instagram.com">Instagram</a>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class= "col-sm-6">
                    <h6>Types of Payment</h6>
                    <p>
                       <a href="http://www.paypal.com"><img src="includes/img/paypal.png" width=44 height=30 align="center"></a>
                       <img src="includes/img/mastercard.png" width=44 height=30 align="center">
                       <img src="includes/img/visa.png" width=44 height=30 align="center">
                    </p>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There must be more code than this.  Where are you detecting SESSION variables..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience with this type of login, it appears that you are returning data from the server in (html), then you are checking (html) to see if it contains the word true. In your PHP code, you have not echoed the word "true". Also, I recommended using the following code on the redirect:

```
window.location.href=""; return false;
```

That seems to have better results in the applications I have written.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify this below code block and check. so that your ajax will get response as 'true' and will be going to your true block

```html
if($count == 1){

    $_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = 'password';
    echo "true";exit;

}
```